# phpmyadmin doesn't respond after timeout. What can I do?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made a query in phpmyadmin that took a long time and in the end it timed out.
After it timed out, I have been unable to access phpmyadmin again. 
I don't get an error, the website just keeps loading and nothing happens.

I've tried accessing the database via scripts, and that works fine, just can't use phpmyadmin.

This has happened a few time before, always after timing out. And I've always just had to wait for quite some time. I usually just try again a few hours later or the next day and then it works. But, that is a bit annoying when I am working on something.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening (other than just making sure my queries won't take so long)? It feels like phpmyadmin is still working on the query, even though it timed out, and that's why it doesn't respond, but I would just like it to stop running the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can reboot the service, I mean, the apache in order to clean buffers etc. Also I recommend you to show the current connections with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`